# Why there is warning in Android Studio clickable attribute found please also add focusable

Tags: android, android-layout

I dont like to do much stuff in layout with xml, but I can read it well and everything is working. Why this warning is there ? I can disable it for sure, but I just don't understand it. I just want that bottom view catch click events so they don't get under, this seems working good and clickable is doing it, so I don't need focusable there at all, but I see it...

Comment: Please post your layout file and also put what type of Warning u are facing ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For accessibility purposes. For instance, if the user is navigating through the keyboard, they can not move onto the clickable item without focusable attribute, hence cannot click.

Reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/KeyboardNavigationDetector.java?autodive=0%2F